# compare DDL (2blocks) with bash

Tags: bash, awk

I need to compare two DDL for the same table in order to see if there were changes (i.e. data type change, new columns, deleted columns ) which have this format: DDL_1.txt

```
CREATE TABLE DB.TABLE_1
(
 COLUMN_1 VARCHAR(20)
 COLUMN_2 DATE(20)
 COLUMN_3 CHAR(1)
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX PI_TABLE1
(
  COLUMN_1,
  COLUMN_2
) ON TABLE_1;
```

and DDL_2.txt

```
CREATE TABLE DB.TABLE_1
(
 COLUMN_1 VARCHAR(20)
 COLUMN_2 DATE(20)
 COLUMN_3 CHAR(1)
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX PI_TABLE1
(
  COLUMN_1,
  COLUMN_2
) ON TABLE_1;
```

in this example they are identical - so no changes should be detected.
I am using this awk program for the comparison:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} 
       $1 in a {if(a[$1]!=$2) print > ("changed"); 
                delete a[$1]; next} 
               {print > ("added")} 
           END {for(k in a) print k,a[k] > ("deleted")}' file1 file2
```

but I am always getting the "changed" and "added" file generated and I can't understand why.
as attempt, I tried to removed from both ddl files the part relative to the creation of the unique index, and the awk program works.
what I mean is, if I compare only

```
CREATE TABLE DB.TABLE_1
(
 COLUMN_1 VARCHAR(20)
 COLUMN_2 DATE(20)
 COLUMN_3 CHAR(1)
);
```

it works.
could please someone explain me why and help to adjust the awk to work with the "full" version of the dml?

adding examples with differences:
DDL_1.txt

```
CREATE TABLE DB.TABLE_1
(
 COLUMN_1 VARCHAR(20),
 COLUMN_2 DATE(20),
 COLUMN_3 CHAR(1),
 COLUMN_4 CHAR(1)
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX PI_TABLE1
(
  COLUMN_1,
  COLUMN_2
) ON TABLE_1;
```

DDL_2.txt:

```
CREATE TABLE DB.TABLE_1
(
 COLUMN_1 VARCHAR(50),
 COLUMN_2 DATE(20),
 COLUMN_3 CHAR(1),
 COLUMN_5 CHAR(10),
 COLUMN_6 INTEGER,
 COLUMN_7 DATE()
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX PI_TABLE1
(
  COLUMN_1,
  COLUMN_2
) ON TABLE_1;
```

so expected output:

```
changed: should contain COLUMN_1 VARCHAR(50), (because the datatype has changed from VARCHAR(20) to VARCHAR(50)
```

```
added: should contain COLUMN_5 CHAR(10) , COLUMN_6 and COLUMN_7 (as it is not existing in DDL_1.txt)
```

```
deleted: should contain COLUMN_4 CHAR(1) as no longer exists in DDL_2.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a start to a simple approach of reading each block from both files into an array and then comparing block by block and line by line in the END section. Given this it should be easy to add whatever logic you like for doing comparisons and printing to different files:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    RS = ""
    ORS = "\n\n"
    FS = OFS = "\n"
}
{
    fileNr = (NR == FNR ? 1 : 2)
    numBlocks[fileNr] = FNR
    blocks[fileNr,numBlocks[fileNr]] = $0
}
END {
    maxBlocks = (numBlocks[1] > numBlocks[2] ? numBlocks[1] : numBlocks[2])
    for ( blockNr=1; blockNr<=maxBlocks; blockNr++ ) {
        printf "\n##########\nAnalyzing block #%d\n", blockNr | "cat>&2"
        if ( (blockNr <= numBlocks[1]) && (blockNr <= numBlocks[2]) ) {
            # This block exists in both files
            numLines1 = split(blocks[1,blockNr],lines1)
            numLines2 = split(blocks[2,blockNr],lines2)
            maxLines = (numLines1 > numLines2 ? numLines1 : numLines2)
            for ( lineNr=1; lineNr<=maxLines; lineNr++ ) {
                if ( (lineNr <= numLines1) && (lineNr <= numLines2) ) {
                    # This line exists in both blocks
                    line1 = lines1[lineNr]
                    line2 = lines2[lineNr]
                    if (line1 == line2) {
                        # do nothing?
                    }
                    else {
                        printf "Difference at block #%d, line %d: \n   < %s\n   > %s\n", blockNr, lineNr, line1, line2 | "cat>&2"
                    }
                }
                else {
                   # check/report which file is missing this line in this block
                }
            }
        }
        else {
           # check/report which file is missing this block
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk DDL_1.txt DDL_2.txt

##########
Analyzing block #1
Difference at block #1, line 3:
   <  COLUMN_1 VARCHAR(20),
   >  COLUMN_1 VARCHAR(50),
Difference at block #1, line 6:
   <  COLUMN_4 CHAR(1)
   >  COLUMN_5 CHAR(10),
Difference at block #1, line 7:
   < );
   >  COLUMN_6 INTEGER,

##########
Analyzing block #2
```